# Sequentially grouping html content by tag

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a html file similar to the following:

```
    <h2>section 1</h2>
    <p>para 1</p>
    <p>para 2</p>
    <p>para 3</p>
    <h2>section 2</h2>
    <p>para 1</p>
    <p>para 2</p>
    <p>para 3</p>
    <h2>section 3</h2>
    <p>para 1</p>
    <p>para 2</p>
    <p>para 3</p>
```

I would like to scrape those into a python dictionary: `{'section1':'...', 'section2':'...', 'section3':'...'}`, of course I can set a `current_section` variable and use a while loop, but is there a module for this purpose?
I have checked out BeautifulSoup but didn't find a shortcut there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's nothing along the lines of `soup.group_by_header()`, but for the input you describe, what you want is fairly straightforward to achieve in any case:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup     
>>> html = """
...     <h2>section 1</h2>
...     <p>para 1</p>
...     <!-- etc. -->
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> sections = {}
>>> for header in soup("h2"):
...     paras = []
...     for sibling in header.find_next_siblings(text=False):
...         if sibling.name == "h2":
...             break
...         paras.append(sibling.string)
...     sections[header.string] = paras
... 
>>> sections
{u'section 1': [u'para 1', u'para 2', u'para 3'],
 u'section 2': [u'para 1', u'para 2', u'para 3'],
 u'section 3': [u'para 1', u'para 2', u'para 3']}
>>>
```

Is that approach problematic for some reason, or were you just wondering whether there's some clever BeautifulSoup method kicking around that suits (and to be fair, there are a few of those)?

Comment: Thank you, this looks really nice. But if there are, as you said, some clever BeautifulSoup method kicking around, please share these also, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `string` builtin's `split` method.  If the text you've got there is in `html_string` you can do

```
sections = html_string.split('<h2>')  #this deletes the opening h2 tag
for section in sections:
    section = '<h2>' + section   #replace the opening h2 tag
    #code to parse each section goes here
```

That should be much cleaner than using a `while` loop.

Comment: This is a bad idea - using an HTML parser is the much better option.

Comment: This can divide the whole html page into groups, but will not extract the text out of it into a dictionary.